# Lense distortion correction with unity5

Tags: c#, unity, virtual-reality

I am working on lens distortion correction in Unity. I created a new scene dragged the "Cardboard" prefab to the scene. In the cardboard setting I have set the Distortion correction as "Non". and I havent made  any changes to the **CardboadDistortion.cginc** shader code.  But still the performance is not clear.What will be the issue.How can I improve the performance.

I am using Unity 5.3.5
GoogleVRForUnity Package

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to solve here. Usually "performance" is used to refer to the game's execution speed — are you experiencing low framerate? But you say it's "not clear" — are you asking about the way the rendered scene blurs & smears in some areas when applying a lens distortion correction effect? Please edit your question to be more explicit about what your problem is and what you're trying to fix.

Comment: I am asking about the way the scene smears in some area. Actually I am working on a walthrough of an environment. When I moved the moved the head from left t right the movement is not smooth and clear.